# account lockout policy - what happen user tried logon with wrong password 3 and use the correct PWD on 4th time?

Tags: active-directory, password-policy

Password settings attribute in question:

- A number of failed login attempts value set to 4.
- Reset failed logon attempt counter reset to after 1 min

Scenario:

When the user use the wrong password to login thrice and he used the right password on 4th time. Within a min, he lock the system and tried with the wrong password.

In the above scenario will the account lockout or will it reset the counter?

Answer (score 0):

A successful login should clear the bad password counter on the PDC Emulator.  This attribute does not replicate.

Comment: HI Thanks for the response. Just to make sure we both are in same page . The counter will not reset unless and until its exceed the counter reset to specified value . for instance user tried 2 bad password attempt and the 3rd on was successful right after he lock the system and tried again with bad password with in the specified value ( 1 min) the account will locked out.

Comment: correct me if am wrong.